# MLP to learn addition

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I want to train a neural net to add two numbers. Using some examples, I've got to here and have achieved a low loss. I want to generate new numbers and pass them to the model to see what the outcomes are, and start to give it two numbers to see what it predicts. Here's what I have:

```
torch.manual_seed(42)

N = 1000  # number of samples
D = 2     # Input dimension
C = 1     # Output dimension
lr = 1e-2 # learning rate

X = torch.rand(N, D)                      # 1000 numbers of 2 dims
y = torch.sum(X, axis=-1).reshape(-1, C)  # This is summing X rows and reshaping it to 1 output dimension

# print(X\[:50\])

# print(y\[:50\])

model = torch.nn.Sequential(torch.nn.Linear(D, C))

criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)

for i in range(500):
    y_pred = model(X)
    loss = criterion(y_pred, y)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    if i % 50 == 0:
        print(i)
        print('---')
        print(loss)

idx = torch.tensor(\[3, 4\])
for i in range(20):
    n = model.generate(idx, 50)
    print(n)
```

I am not able to generate from this model and am not sure how.

Comment: "I am not able to generate from this model", what is `model.generate` supposed to perform? Your model is not supposed to generate anything. it just outputs a tensor given another tensor. What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

To generate an output with the model you can simply call the model on an input `X`:

```
y_pred = model(X)
```

An example implementation of your script could be:

```
torch.manual_seed(42)

N = 1000  # number of samples
D = 2     # Input dimension
C = 1     # Output dimension
lr = 1e-1 # learning rate

X = torch.rand(N, D)                      # 1000 numbers of 2 dims
y = torch.sum(X, axis=-1).reshape(-1, C)  # This is summing X rows and reshaping it to 1 output dimension

print(f"X.shape: {X.shape}, y.shape:{y.shape}")
print(f"X[:5]: {X[:5]}")
print(f"y[:5]: {y[:5]}")

model = torch.nn.Sequential(torch.nn.Linear(D, C))
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)

print("\nTraining model")
for i in range(500):
    y_pred = model(X)
    loss = criterion(y_pred, y)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    if i % 50 == 0:
        print(f"Epoch: {i+1:<5} loss: {loss.item()}")

print("\nTesting trained model on new random numbers")
for i in range(5):
    X = torch.rand(1, D)
    y_pred = model(X)
    print(f"{X[:, 0].item():.2f} + {X[:, 1].item():.2f} = {X.sum().item():.2f}, predicted: {y_pred.item():.2f}")

print(f"\nModel learned weights and biases\n{model.state_dict()}")
```

This is the output of the above implementation:

```
X.shape: torch.Size([1000, 2]), y.shape:torch.Size([1000, 1])
X[:5]: tensor([[0.8823, 0.9150],
        [0.3829, 0.9593],
        [0.3904, 0.6009],
        [0.2566, 0.7936],
        [0.9408, 0.1332]])
y[:5]: tensor([[1.7973],
        [1.3422],
        [0.9913],
        [1.0502],
        [1.0740]])

Training model
Epoch: 1     loss: 1.1976375579833984
Epoch: 51    loss: 0.013810846023261547
Epoch: 101   loss: 1.6199066521949135e-05
Epoch: 151   loss: 2.2864621485041425e-07
Epoch: 201   loss: 1.5489435289950393e-09
Epoch: 251   loss: 1.0740366929162803e-11
Epoch: 301   loss: 5.607882254811229e-14
Epoch: 351   loss: 4.732325513424554e-18
Epoch: 401   loss: 1.3877788466974007e-20
Epoch: 451   loss: 1.3877788466974007e-20

Testing trained model on new random numbers
0.29 + 0.47 = 0.77, predicted: 0.77
0.15 + 0.45 = 0.60, predicted: 0.60
0.57 + 0.48 = 1.05, predicted: 1.05
0.31 + 0.65 = 0.96, predicted: 0.96
0.37 + 0.22 = 0.59, predicted: 0.59

Model learned weights and biases
OrderedDict([('0.weight', tensor([[1., 1.]])), ('0.bias', tensor([2.3689e-09]))])
```

Note: I changed the learning rate from `1e-2` to `1e-1` so that the model optimization converges to a low training loss.

Also, you can verify that the trained model has weights `[[1., 1.]]` and bias `[2.3689e-09]`, which means that the model has learned to add two numbers as `y_pred = x_0 * 1 + x_1 * 1 + 2.3689e-09`.